# How can I get same hierarchy from UITestControl same as in CUIT assertion from

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am writing small utility on top up MS Coded UI. I want to get same hierarchy from UITestControl as shown in Coded UI assertion form.
I am constructing UITestControl as shown in below code

```
 UITestControl test = UITestControlFactory.FromPoint(Mouse.Location);
```

After that I want to get control hierarchy.

Is there any way?

Regards,
Rajendar.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to write the code for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See also the help pages (linked at the top of every page) for how to write a good question.

Comment: To get control hierarchy we are using   uiTechnologyElement.QueryId.Ancestor but in some cases it different from hierarchy shown in CUIT assertion form. Is there any different way to get ancestor hierarchy using UItechnologyElement or UITestControl

Comment: You have tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getparent.aspx haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
test.GetParent().GetChildren();
```

It will return UITestControlCollection and you can foreach through it